# Firebase Functions Realtime Database converting array to objects problem

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When i try add new data to firebase realtime database its converting my array to objects.
Example:

```
"POINTS": [{
  "w":237.00004067230424,
  "x":0,
  "y":0,
  "h":8.996961455599944
},
{
  "w":68.00003035736216,
  "h":243.99697579886254,
  "x":237,
  "y":9
}]
```

in Realtime Database:

```
"POINTS":{
  "0":{
    "h":0.9969740288429421,
    "w":96.00002364349457,
    "x":0,
    "y":0
  },
  "1":{
    "h":163.99698397757402,
    "w":41.000020286560755,
    "x":97,
    "y":1
  }
}
```

how can i solve this problem?
I want to get array like i tried to insert

My codes:

in firebase functions:
my array is part of request body

```
exports.createDB = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  const myRequest = request.body;
  
  functions.logger.info(String(request.body));
  database.ref("diagram/"+myRequest.user.uid).set(myRequest);
  response.send(request.body);
});
```

I am sending the data using postman

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem!  --- Instead of posting the solution in your question, can you post it below as answer? That way others are more likely to see it, and the also system knows you've been helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED problem: When i get data using this function

```
database.ref("diagram/"+request.body.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    //response.send(snapshot);
    response.json(snapshot);
  });
```

but changed it solved my problem

```
database.ref("diagram/"+request.body.uid).get().then(function(snapshot) {
    response.json(snapshot.val());
  });
```